# How to mock jpa repository save(without return object) and modify id of input object

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mockito

I use Spring Data JPA in my project and my model code is here:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Activity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String number;
//...
}
```

My service code is here:

```
activityRepository.save(activity);//activity has no data in field id
activity.setNumber("D"+activity.getId()); //A
activityRepository.save(activity);
```

And my mock code is here:

```
when(activityRepository.save(activity)).thenReturn(tempActivity);
//invoke service method
verify(activityRepository).save(activity);
```

The question is that I have always been met with the Null Pointer Exception in code A.So how can I mock this repository save method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two points:

1. Use the returned object from activityRepository.save(activity)

   ```java
   activity = activityRepository.save(activity);//activity has no data in field id
   activity.setNumber("D"+activity.getId()); //A
   activity = activityRepository.save(activity);
   ```
2. Return a modified version, that is returned by the mock

   ```java
   tempActivity = activity.toBuilder().id(5).build();
   when(activityRepository.save(activity)).thenReturn(tempActivity);
   //invoke service method
   verify(activityRepository).save(activity);
   ```